# Issue with color profile of CMYK image

Tags: colors, rgb, graphicsmagick, cmyk, color-profile

## TL;DR

I'm chasing a color problem that occurs for one of our images which appears in different green tones in different viewers.

## The source image

- Most image viewers render it **light green**.

  - including Chrome, XnView
- Some image viewers render it **dark green**:

  - including Safari, Faststone Image Viewer

#### Source File to download:

(Depending on your browser this will appear to you light or dark green)

[image]

#### The difference (hard-coded for illustration)

Note: The **dark green color** is the intended color tone.

[image]

## To persist the issue

Running `gm convert isolated-in.jpg png:isolated-out.png` persists this light green for all image renderes.

### The desired information I'm lacking

I understand that there must be a corruption of the color profile of the source image. Infact, there seems to be no Color profile set. However, some image tools render it correctly, making me beliefe there is a different "guess" on the profile.

1. What are those image tools doing so that it appears dark green?
2. What is the correct description of the Color profile missing, IPTC, XMP, ICC profile missing?
3. on top of everything the source image are CMYK. Does that play a role?

### The desired solution

Can I, with `gm identify` and/or `gm convert` correct for the missing/corrupted color profile of the source and persist the correct color, which is dark green, by a better guess of the color profile?

Comment: Stackoverflow is probably not the right forum for this question. Maybe try https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com ? Anyway, I'm pretty sure CMYK plays a key-role here. I'm not an expert, but this looks like a "classical" RGB to CMYK mapping (RGB lighter, CMYK darker). I assume if you print the light version on paper, it will look more or less like the dark version. Some software is able to simulate this, if it knows the intended profile is CMYK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/160359/issue-with-color-profile-of-cmyk-image I found the solution for us:

```
convert -profile "U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2.icm" input.jpg -profile sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc out-27.png
```

I downloaded the two profiles from official sources.